# filter firstname from 3 map() in react js

Tags: reactjs

i have this input filed in my code for serching the list i have 3 catagery of list which are displayed by three map() i want to input a name in the input fild and if it exist i want to show the `firstname` just like whatsapps serach works

```
<form style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              
                <input
                  className="w-100 msserserch gradiantblur"
                  placeholder="seach messages"
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    this.setState({ serchinput: e.target.value })
                  }
                  type="Search"
                />
              </form>
```

the map() are given below there are 3 i want when i type in input  fild fistname mustbe filterd from this

```
 {this.state.tablist == "doctor" ? (
                    <div
                      className="chat-avatar gradiantblur"
                      onClick={() => this.livechat(this.state.list.id)}
                    >
                      <div></div>
                      <div className="alignstart">
                        {this.state.list.firstname} {this.state.list.lastname}
                        <p className="margin-0">
                          {" "}
                          {this.state.list.speciality}
                        </p>
                        <p className="margin-0">
                      
                          &#10003; {this.state.list.speciality}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div>152:11</div>
                    </div>
                  ) : this.state.tablist == "consultant" ? (
                    <>
                      <div className="scrollerchatlist">
                        {console.log(this.state.consulatnt)}
                        {this.state.consulatnt.map((data) => (
                          <div
                            className="chat-avatar gradiantblur"
                            onClick={() => this.livechat(data.id)}
                          >
                            <div>
                      
                            </div>
                            <div className="alignstart">
                              {data.firstname} {data.lastname}
                              <p className="margin-0"> {data.speciality}</p>
                              <p className="margin-0">
                            
                                &#10003; {data.firstname}
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <div>152:11</div>
                          </div>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    </>
                  ) : this.state.tablist == "sales" ? (
                    <>
                     
                      <div className="scrollerchatlist">
                        {this.state.sales.map((data) => (
                          <div
                            className="chat-avatar gradiantblur"
                            onClick={() => this.livechat(data.id)}
                          >
                            <div>
                          
                            </div>
                            <div className="alignstart">
                              {data.firstname}
                            
                              <p className="margin-0">
                              
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <div>152:11</div>
                          </div>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    </>
                  ) : null}
```

my code is big so i put it in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-nova-v7pb1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I see in your code, you have this.state.tablist which is deciding what to render when any tab gets selected. So whenever user types in the input, you can just filter out firstname string from all three array and render them in your list:

```
onChange={this.onSearchTextChange}

onSearchTextChange(event) {
  const query = event.query.target;
  if(query){
    const dataSet = [this.state.sales, this.state.consultants, ...];
    const filteredName = dataSet.map(
        data => data.filter(row => row.firstName).filter(Boolean)
    ).flat();
    // now set the state with this data
    this.setState({...});
  }
}
```

Comment: sultan thanks for the answe but can u edit my codesandbox so that i can undersand where i shold be appling the code u gave thanx sir in advance

Comment: sultan can u help out bro